# Non-negative solutions of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear system
$$A x = b $$
with $A$ being an $m \times n$ matrix ($m < n $) and $b $ being an $n $ vector, both over $\mathbb R_{\geq 0} $ (non-negative real numbers).

The system is guaranteed to have at least one non-negative solution (not known to us). I want to find the set of all non-negative solutions of the system.

Comment: Are you assuming "The system is guaranteed to have at least one non-negative solution"?

Comment: Yes, that's why I  wrote that :)

Comment: I guess you are looking for: http://mathoverflow.net/q/30048/14319

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/715807/9464

Comment: Oh, that's great, thanks!